# How to deal with CSS overflow?

Tags: html, css

I have an overflow menu. It is very long, but has the following style:

```css
height: 15rem;
overflow-y: auto;
```

[image]

Nevertheless when I click on the menu the browser window height becomes bigger as if the menu is opened in is full size (see the difference between browser scrollbar in the first and second pictures. Besides I have empty space below my page reserved for the full-size menu.
**So the invisible part of the menu nevertheless takes space.** How could I fix that?

[image]

Code:

```
    <DataTable>
      <TableContainer>
        <TableToolbar>
          <TableToolbarContent>
            <TableToolbarSearch/>
            <TableToolbarMenu>
              <div style={ {display: displayMenu ? "block" : "none", height: "7.5rem", width: "230px", overflowY: "auto"}}>
                {filterItems.map(e => { return (
                <TableToolbarAction // onClick={ ()=> setItemClicked({...e, defaultChecked: false})} onChange = {() => { setDisplayMenu(true); if(headers.map(el => el.key).includes(e.key)) { setHeaders(headers.filter(el => el.key !== e.key)); } else { setHeaders([ ...headers, { key: e.key, header:
                  e.header } ]) } }} hasDivider = {true} >
                  <Checkbox defaultChecked={ true} id={ e.key} labelText={ e.header}/>
                </TableToolbarAction>
                ) })}
              </div>
            </TableToolbarMenu>
          </TableToolbarContent>
        </TableToolbar>
    </DataTable>
```

Comment: Could you provide code or a link so we can see the problem for ourselves? 
It is very hard to identify the problem just based on partial screenshots.

Comment: Note that the code presented is lacking a closing `</TableContainer>` tag. It also appears to be using React, as the only HTML tag in there is `<div>`, and that has some serious issues with its syntax. Be sure to tag your questions correctly. Finally, we have no idea what the length of your page nor the menu is, so it is not evident, from the screenshot, that the page is expanding to include the height of the entire menu. Please include a [mre].

Answer (score -1):

Use `overflow: scroll;` to give a scrollbar or use `overflow: hidden;` to hide the  overflow.

Comment: The OP has `overflow-y: auto;`, which will show the vertical scrollbar when needed.